# counting individual characters in a large list of passwords without killing loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a count on, for example, how many a's are in a massive list of passwords out of curiosity. but i think when i'm trying to add a count for a character it's killing the loop that is going through all the characters.

```html
#Examine passwords.txt

file = open('passwords.txt','r')
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
g = 0
h = 0
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
l = 0
m = 0
n = 0
o = 0
p = 0
q = 0
r = 0
s = 0
t = 0
u = 0
v = 0
w = 0
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0

with open('passwords.txt','r') as fileobj:
    for line in fileobj:
       for char in line:
           if char == a:
               a += 1
           elif char == b:
               b += 1
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
print(e)
print(f)
```

Comment: Do you mean `if char == 'a'` and `elif char == 'b'`?

Comment: yes, when i run it i get those as being 0, and there's 1,000,000 passwords in my list so there's quite a few more than 0

Comment: Well, the code as written will always produce 0 because you forgot to put quotes around the `a` and `b`.

Comment: thanks lol, i didn't even think of that lol. you have fixed my issue

Comment: a text file of 1 million passwords seems, uh, nefarious at best

Comment: or just curiosity :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `dictionary` (or a `list` which has an order) to store how many counts of each letter there are. This is *much* better than using `26` one letter variables which is ridiculous!

To create a dictionary, you can use a dictionary-comprehension with `str.count` on the entire contents of the file.

```
with open('passwords.txt','r') as fileobj:
    text = fileobj.read()
    letterCounts = {c: text.count(c) for c in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}
```

which would give `letterCounts` as something like:

```
{'s': 0, 'a': 4, 'o': 0, 'i': 0, 'm': 0, 'k': 0, 'q': 0, 'y': 0, 'c': 1, 'j': 0, 'b': 4, 'g': 0, 'd': 1, 'h': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'u': 0, 'n': 0, 'w': 0, 't': 0, 'x': 0, 'p': 0, 'l': 0, 'r': 0, 'z': 0, 'v': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

with open('passwords.txt','r') as fileobj:
    counts = Counter()
    for line in fileobj:
        counts.update(line)
```

`counts` is a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) keeping track of the counts of all the characters that appear in the file.  YOu would access the number of `a`s with `counts['a']`